# (Antlr) How can I run this input and get output in terminal?

Tags: java, command-line, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to run this code in my command line. After I run this, I can type input in my command line

[image: Command Line]

How do I run my input and get output? What buttons should I press?

```
import java.io.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class ParseMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    //ProjLangLexer lexer = new ProjLangLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]));
    ProjLangLexer lexer = new ProjLangLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(System.in));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    ProjLangParser parser = new ProjLangParser(tokens);
    parser.input();


    //ScanMain
    Token tok = lexer.nextToken();
    while (tok.getType() != Token.EOF) {
    System.out.println("Lexeme = " + tok.getText() + " Token = " + tok.getType());
        tok = lexer.nextToken();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+Z then Enter to simulate EOF if in windows command line. If using unix, try Ctrl+D.